Where did this 45+ year old red wine come from?
We have a red wine that we've been aging since we bought it in about 1977.
At some point in history, one of our dogs had urinated on the bottle and made the label fall off.
We've been saving this for a special occasion, but we no longer even know the brand.  It has a very unique bottle shape, so I am hoping that someone may have an idea of what it is based on that.  Does this bottle provide any clues?
1)
2)
3)

Where did this 45+ year old red wine come from?
This certainly is a Chianti wine from the region of Tuscany, Italy.

Chianti is an Italian red wine produced in the Chianti region of central Tuscany, principally from the Sangiovese grape. It was historically associated with a squat bottle enclosed in a straw basket, called a fiasco. However, the fiasco is now only used by a few makers of the wine; most Chianti is bottled in more standard-shaped wine bottles. In the latter nineteenth century, Baron Bettino Ricasoli (later Prime Minister of the Kingdom of Italy) helped establish Sangiovese as the blend's dominant grape variety, creating the blueprint for today's Chianti wines. - Chianti

The bottle you posted is what is known as a fiasco of flask. These styles of bottle are no longer is production as of the 1990s.

I know Chianti bottles that are so long, but here there's no typical basket lining (which would've probably survived the dog incident).

Maybe more information about where you bought the wine will help you to limit what it could be.
With some luck, there is some information on the winegrower or region on the cork. But with such an old bottle, the cork is often no longer optimally intact.
